# identity server 4 authorize clients for certain user only

Tags: asp.net-identity, client, identityserver4

In Identity server 4 How do I set User "alice" can access Client1, client4 but can not access client2 and client3. Please provide some examples. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You typically control that in the Authorization step in each client, not in IdentityServer. OpenIDConnect/Token is all about who is the user (authentication).

Internally, in a typical ASP.NET Core application you have these modules as shown in the picture below.

[image]

The first authentication module is in charge of establishing who is the user. This is what we use OpenID connect.

The second part is all about what is the person allowed to access. So to reduce the complexity of the application, then don't try to mix authentication and authorization.

This video is a good stating point. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJeZ3YNnqz8&ab_channel=NDCConferences

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand this. Do you have any sample or example?